# Excel: Sum only values which have a number value above itself?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'am trying to create a function which only sum values which have a number value above itself.

I now have this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:EE1000;AND(ISNUMBER(OFFSET(A2:EE1000;-1;0));ISNUMBER(OFFSET(A3:EE1000;-1;0))))
```

But it returns 0. I need it to return 20 (according to the attached image example).

I would also like to count the number of cells which have a number value above itself.

Example

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the secondary part of your post, "I would also like to count the number of cells which have a number value above itself", this formula will answer:

=SUM(IF(A1:L5*A2:L6>0,1,0)). It's an array formula with an arbitrarily assumed range of where your data resides, as you may have already seen.